# Socket IO and Angular duplicate issue

Tags: websocket

I am getting duplicate issue when moving from one room to another. I use websocket in nestjs backend project and angular as a client.

Simply, I am trying to move from one room to another but **socket.fromEvent** returns duplicates and duplicates increase once I login to another rooms.

```js
Server

import {
    SubscribeMessage,
    WebSocketGateway,
    OnGatewayInit,
    WebSocketServer,
    OnGatewayConnection,
    OnGatewayDisconnect,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Socket, Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway({ transports: ['websocket', 'polling'] })
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit {

    @WebSocketServer() wss: Server;

    afterInit(server: any) {}

    @SubscribeMessage('send-message')
    handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: any) {
        this.wss.to(payload.userroom).emit('message', { msg: payload.text, when: payload.when, user: payload.user })
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('join')
    handleConnection(client: Socket, room: string) {
        client.join(room)
    }
    @SubscribeMessage('leave')
    handleDisconnect(client: Socket, room: string) {
        client.leave(room)
    }

}


Client

// connect, leave & join when moving from room to another
getChatMessagesAndStartSession(sessionId: number, userChat: number) {
  this.clearChatContent();
  this.activeSessionId = sessionId;
  this.activeChat = userChat;
  this.messages = messages;
  this.socket.connect()
  this.socket.emit('leave', this.beforesession);
  this.socket.emit('join', this.activeSessionId);
  this.beforesession = this.activeSessionId;
  this.socket.fromEvent('message').subscribe((message: any) => {
    console.log(message)
    this.messages.push(message);
    this.scrollToBottom();

  });
}

// send message to 
sendSocketMessage() {
this.socket.emit('send-message', { text: this.respondMessage, when: new Date, user: this.user_id })
}
```

Result:

[image]